# APNS Assistant not launching on Apple Dev Provisioning Site

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I just want to see if I am going crazy or not. I have the following App Ids in the provisioning portal.

com.foo.*
com.foo
com.foo.FooApp

The first was for before we needed push.
The second was a mistake, but I can't delete it.
The third is for my current push notifications

The problem that I have is that the APNS assistant will not launch when I click the configure button for my com.foo.FooApp App Id. I created the push certificates and then revoked them, but am unable to recreate...?

Thanks!
mark

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The APNS assistant doesn't launch when I click the configure button. Tried everything I can think of, like creating additional AppID's and then trying to configure the SSL certs for those, but same result - clicking the configure button does nothing.

Also reported it to Apple (2010/10/12) -no response yet.

Just tried again (2010/10/15) - Apple fixed the issue. All working